# Initialize class properties without creating a constructor python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
class MyClass:
    a = None
    b = None
```

now I have this part in my code:

```
my_class_instance = MyClass(a=3, b=5)
```

I am getting this error:

`TypeError: MyClass() takes no arguments`

Is there a way to initialize `MyClass` with values for `a` and `b` without creating a constructor?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html? Maybe a https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is a dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    a: int
    b: int

mc = MyClass(a=3, b=5)
```

Comment: Thanks.
Do I have to declare the properties type?
what if I want it to be generic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931096/how-to-add-a-dataclass-field-without-annotating-the-type answers that question.

Comment: @Kenny in theory, you can wrap The annotation in the string in order to forward declare it, so for example `a : ‘I really have no idea what I’m doing!’` and Python will like that just fine.

Comment: note that replacing angular quotes with normal quotes `'` is necessary, because I was typing on my phone.

Comment: Though in all fairness, you can also annotate a field as `typing.Any` if you don't know beforehand what type the variable is going to have. In practice however, generally you can narrow down it down to a few possible types, so in that case you can use `typing.Union` instead. For example, `a: 'int | str | bool'` if you know that field `a` can be any of those types, and so an IDE can also offer you type hints accordingly. In Python 3.10, you can unwrap it from a string and just declare it explicitly, as the pipe `|` operator is supported for builtin types.