# dataclass behaviour in derived class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I ran into this bizzare behaviour of dataclasses when intermixed with inheritance/type annotations:

```py
>>> @dataclass
... class Base:
...     a: int = 10
...
>>>
>>> @dataclass
... class Derived(Base):
...     a = 20
...
>>>
>>> Derived.a
20
>>> Derived().a
10
```

Note that if I add annotation on `a` in `Derived`, then things behave reasonably.

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a: int` in a dataclass declares an instance attribute, because that is how dataclasses are designed to work. (See [dataclasses documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass).)

`a = 20` in `Derived` defines a class attribute, because that is how class attributes are defined. So the class `Derived` has an attribute `a` with the value 20, but an instance of `Derived` has (inherited from `Base`) an instance attribute with the default value 10.

See also [How to add a dataclass field without annotating the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49931096/3890632)

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) mentions the following:

> The `dataclass()` decorator examines the class to find `field`s. A `field` is defined as a class variable that has a type annotation. [...]

Hence, in the definition of `Derived`, `a = 20` is not identified as a field and thus it is not added to the `__init__` method of the class. When creating an instance of that class, it will use the original parameter definition from `Base` which has `10` as a default value.